# Is this possible? Using only an one liner JavaScript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I convert this into an one-liner JavaScript regex?

```
html.replace(/src="(.*?)"/gi, function($1)
{  return $1.replace(/(abc.*?)\/abc/gi, "abc");
});
```

The above code block should be self-explanatory of what I'm trying to accomplish, but I'll elaborate.

What I'm trying to accomplish is replace all matches of this regex /src="(.*?)"/ which contains the substring: abc[random_characters]/abc to just abc. And so for example

src="abc[random_characters]/abc[random_characters]" => src="abc[random_characters]"

Edit: One-liner without the anonymous function call or callback.

Edit: Solution

```
html.replace(/src="abc(?:.*?)\/(abc[^"]+)"/gi, "src=\"$1\"");
```

Comment: html.replace(/src="(.*?)"/gi, function($1) {  return $1.replace(/(abc.*?)\/abc/gi, "abc");});  ha ha -- 1 line, just got rid of the carriage returns.

Comment: Your requirements are unclear, please add concret examples of original strings and expected results.

Comment: Maybe I should be clear on it. I should of have said one-liner without the function call or callback.

Comment: Note that the solutions below won't work if src doesn't start with `abc`. Are you sure it is what you want?

Comment: abc was just arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

Use backreference:

```
html.replace(/src="(abc[^\/]*\/?)+"/gi, 'src="$1"');
```

- `(abc[^\/]*\/?)` — matches abc + random characters (except for `/`);
- `"$1"` — a backreference to the captured group.

However, I'm not quite sure it satisfies you requirements. Your description of a problem is a little bit inconsistent.

Comment: Somewhat satisfied my requirement, but anyway I figured out already.

Comment: I posted it 2 days ago ;) Anyway, I'm glad you got it running.